# Run two projects with different data sources in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to run two different projects from different instances in Visual studio. The idea is that in one, based on a virtual machine, I want to test some long running processes. But so that I can continue with other work I want to run another project on my local machine connecting to a local instance of SQL Server.

Both projects run fine by themselves, the problem occurs when one is run before the other, then the second gets an econn error [image: Error Message] both are running on localhost, one is set to run on part 2060, the other port 2070

Anyone know a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The issue was with Java debugging. It seems that with it enabled it will not run the two simultaneously. With each on a different port and Java debugging disabled, it runs perfectly.